# Disable "Smart Rotate" feature in Android

Tags: adb, screen

I have been trying to find a way to disable the "smart rotate" feature in my Android tablet with adb commands without any luck.
I hope someone can help me with this.

The smart rotate feature is described as "When enabled, apps that support portrait display only will display content in landscape mode".

[image]

This setting can be found in Settings > Display > Smart Rotate.
The tablet I am using is a Lenovo Tab M10 HD 3rd gen, Android 11.

I have found several commands to enable/disable the auto-rotate feature but none to enable/disable the smart rotate feature.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Smart Rotate is AFAIK a Lenovo specific feature and I am not sure if it is documented how to change it via adb. You may need to extract the settings app from your device, load it in Jadx-GUI and find the settings parameter name you need for change it via adb.

Comment: Hi @Robert thank you for your answer! I have tried what you suggested and I think I have found that with the command `adb shell setprop persist.sys.magic_window_switch false` I could possibly change this. It requires root though :( and I cannot root my tablet for some external reasons.

With `adb shell getprop persist.sys.magic_window_switch` I can get the smart rotation state correctly, I tried changing it manually and it works. 

I am not a pro when it comes to searching for the settings parameter names that could possibly change it, and maybe I missed something